# AJAX JQuery Jsonify like button (logic)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, flask

I am new to JQuery and JS in general, kind of tough for me. The logic itself eludes me.

If I want to add a like button for a post using AJAX, this need to be wrapped in a form, correct? In order to process the POST.

Should I have a button with a value of 0 and then JQuery will update it to a 1 if clicked? Other than the comment section and like button my practice server is complete.

Should I be using a method as follows instead of setting a value attribute?

```
if ($(this).html() == "Like") {
    $(this).html('Unlike').css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

I have a lot of reading up to do on using json to update a variable and the rest of this. If one could share a link to a great article it would be very helpful.